# What is the structure of the JBIG2 filtered stream in the PDF document

Tags: c#, image, pdf, image-processing

Where can I find the structure of the JBIG2 stream, like the byte length of the segment's header, byte length of the individual property in the segment header and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the JBIG specification. This should be on the JPEG website. You may have to browse to find the JBIG part 2 documentation.

http://www.jpeg.org

At the last edit, the JBIG part 2 documentation is here:

http://www.jpeg.org/jbig/documentation.html

You can download a copy from the ITU website. Start at section 7.

Comment: both links seems to be broken :-/